# PHP Function with array return type

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

I have created a function which gets all employee list who has the same salary. But it will return only the first row but I want all the data how can I do it ?

Function code

```
function getEmployee($employee, $salary) {
  $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $employee where salary = '$$salary'");
  if ($select) {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
        $employeeInfo = array(
          'fname' => $row['fname'],
          'mname' => $row['buyQty'],
          'lname' => $row['lname'],
          'employeeCode' => $row['employeeCode'],
          'email' => $row['email'],
          'mobile' => $row['mobile'],
        );
      return $employeeInfo;
    }
  } else {
    echo mysql_error();
  }  
}
```

Function Call

```
$entry[] = getEmployee('abc', '10000');
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_values($entry));
echo "</pre>";
```

Thank You

Comment: Move return statement below while

Comment: @BorisSavic Thanks For help. It's working now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
        $employeeInfo[] = array(
          'fname' => $row['fname'],
          'mname' => $row['buyQty'],
          'lname' => $row['lname'],
          'employeeCode' => $row['employeeCode'],
          'email' => $row['email'],
          'mobile' => $row['mobile'],
        );
}
return $employeeInfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
function getEmployee($employee, $salary) {
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $employee where salary = '$$salary'");
    if ($select) {
      $allEmployeesInfo = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
        $employeeInfo = array(
        'fname' => $row['fname'],
        'mname' => $row['buyQty'],
        'lname' => $row['lname'],
        'employeeCode' => $row['employeeCode'],
        'email' => $row['email'],
        'mobile' => $row['mobile'],
      );
      array_push($allEmployeesInfo, $employeeInfo);
    }
    return $allEmployeesInfo;
  } else {
    echo mysql_error();
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting only one value (the last array in iteration) because you actually overwrites $employeeInfo with every iteration and at the loop termination $employeeInfo retains the last array only.
Make this as array like $employeeInfo[] inside your getEmployee function.